# How to embed fonts in a Java web application?

Tags: fonts, amazon-web-services, java

**This question is generic, but is also related to Amazon Web Services.**

I am trying to deploy a Java application to an Amazon cloud server, but the application fails to start because it uses AWT fonts (see the following lines):

```
TextImage testImage = new TextImageImpl(128, 32, new Margin(0, 8));

// Declare or read the fonts you need
Font header = new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 24);

// 1. specify font and write text with a newline
testImage.useFont(header).writeLine(text).newLine();
```

The issue I am having is that Amazon's virtual servers don't have proper fonts installed and as a result you cannot do image/chart related stuff in your application. See [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=284607) for more information.
Their customer support suggested using a custom VM image (with either fonts or Oracle JDK installed since Oracle JDK comes with a set of fonts) which is not a clean solution for me.

**My question is: 
How can I rewrite my code, or package it in a different way, so that it runs on a fresh installation of Open JDK with no additional fonts needed (if at all possible).**

By the way, here is a part of the error I'm getting:

> Oct 9, 2011 11:05:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ZipGrocery Application
>   threw exception java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found.
>     at sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1088)
>     at sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:967)
>     at
>   sun.font.CompositeFont.doDeferredInitialisation(CompositeFont.java:254)
>     at sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(CompositeFont.java:334)   at
>   sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:77)    at
>   sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)  at
>   sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:358)
>     at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.(FontDesignMetrics.java:349)    at
>   sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:301)     at
>   sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:787)   at
>   nl.jamiecraane.imagegenerator.impl.TextImageImpl.getFontMetrics(TextImageImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   nl.jamiecraane.imagegenerator.impl.TextImageImpl.writeLine(TextImageImpl.java:212)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an actual font you had proper licensing to distribute, you could package, load, and register the font as part of your distributed application.

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("A.ttf"));
return font.deriveFont(24f);
```

I've found OpenJDK to be buggy and unreliable for production environments. I'd just go with Oracle's JDK if you can.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Google Fonts API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this is an option for me (business-wise).